# Catch errors with default for empty indexes

Tags: try-catch, rethinkdb

I try to do:

```
db.table(table)
    .max({index: 'number'})('number')
    .default(0)
```

and receive error:

```
(node:45) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReqlQueryLogicError: `max` found no entries in the specified index in:
r.db("db").table("table").max({"index": "number"})("number").default(0)
```

Is there a way to do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is empty, or doesn't contain elements with the indexed field "number".

You can try the same query without using the number field as index.

```
r.db("DB").table("table")
  .max('number')('number')
  .default(0)
```

Or fill your table with elements. In this case using the field "number" as index brings you performance advantage.

Comment: Well, I decided to insert default value on the first start of the service (it is sync process and that query for max is performed each run of the daemon, so in order to avoid checks for emptiness I insert something on the very start of the service and then run in cycle only with 'max').